# How do i correct the array index for accessing questions in the source code of quiz in Javascript language

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have created a quiz code in Javascript but when i inspect the program ,it is throwing an error for the line --> `question=questions[index][0]`. Here it says

> Uncaught Typeerror :Cannot read of property "0" of undefined.

I do not know what is the solution. Of How else to read the questions array.I have defined the variables properly.Please help

```js
var choiceA, choiceB, choiceC, choiceD, answer, element, correct = 0,
  index;


var questions = [
  ["How many strokes in the Ashoka Chakra?", "12", "24", "32", "10", "B"],
  ["What is 30*2?", "60", "50", "20", "10", "A"],
  [" What is largest fish?  ", "Blue Whale", "Megaladon", "Hammer-head shark", "All the sharks", "B"],
  ["What is the currency of Europe and America respectively?", "Dollar and Euro", "Euro and Dollar", "Yen and Rupees", "Rupees and Yen", "B"],
  ["What is the seven wonders of the World amongst these?", "Taj Mahal", "Great Wall Of China", "Victoria Falls", "All of these", "D"],
  ["What is the main source of travel in Mumbai?", "Trains", "Aeroplane", "Autorickshaw", "Motorcycle", "A"],
  ["How many continents in the World?", "3", "4", "5", "6", "C"],
  ["What  Ocean surrounds India ?", "Indian Ocean", "Pacific Ocean", "Atlantic Ocean", "Arctic Ocean", "A"],
  ["What  station does not come in Mumbai-Railway-Western-Line?", "Sandhurst Road", "Andheri", "Borivali", "Naigaon", "A"],
  ["Who is the CEO of Google  parent company- Alphabet Inc.?", "Madhuri Dixit", "Narendra Modi", "Tim Cook", "Sundar Pichai", "D"]
];

function selectQuestion() {
  element = document.getElementById("select").innerHTML;
  for (index = 0; index <= questions.length; index++) {
  
    question = questions[index][0];
    choiceA = questions[index][1];
    choiceB = questions[index][2];
    choiceC = questions[index][3];
    choiceD = questions[index][4];
    answer = questions[index][5];

    element += question + "<br>";

    element += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'>" + choiceA + "<br>";
    element += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'>" + choiceB + "<br>";
    element += "<input type='radio'  name='choices' value='A'>" + choiceC + "<br>";
    element += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'>" + choiceD + "<br>";
    element += "<input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='checkAnswer()'>" + "<br>";
  }
}

function checkAnswer() {
  var choice = document.getElementsByName("choices").values;
  for (var index2 = 0; index2 <= choices.length; index2++) {
    if (choices[index2].checked == choice) {
      choice = answer;
    }
  }
  if (choice == answer) {
    correct++;
  }
  if (index == questions.length) {
    alert("you have " + correct + "answers out of 10");
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Quiz code</title>
  <style>
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      background-color: lightcoral;
    }
    
    #select {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="selectQuestion()">

  <h1>QUIZ</h1>
  <div id="select"></div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to fix `selectQuestion` for-condition: `index < questions.length`. The same is true for `checkAnswer`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `index < questions.length`, because **array index start from 0 and ends in n-1**.

**An array of length n will have index from 0 to n-1**. So when you try to access element `array[n]` it will be `undefined` because there is no nth element in that array. 
when you try to access `array[n][0]` you are trying to access `undefined[0]`. That is why it throws an error

```
  for (index = 0; index < questions.length; index++) {
                question = questions[index][0];
                choiceA = questions[index][1];
                choiceB = questions[index][2];
                choiceC = questions[index][3];
                choiceD = questions[index][4];
                answer = questions[index][5];
            }
```

Comment: i corrected it . And even changed the <div id = "select1">  still the code is not working.

Comment: `document.getElementById("select").innerHTML = element;`

will append it to the dom